# Can't figure out how to make this GroupBy clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 Tables Company and Car.

```
Company: 
    CompanyId,
    CarId,
    Inative: 1 or 0.

Car:
   CarId,
   Plate.
```

The problem is:
 In the same month a Car could be rented for more than one Company and I have to bring only the last company that the car was rented.

```
SELECT CompanyId
from Company
where
-- Some Business Rules
GroupBy CompanyId
-- I Need to bring only the CompanyId on this query.
-- The company may be inative, but if more than one company used the same car I must return only the last company.
```

I Can't figure out how I write this GroupBy Clause. Since if i put CarId on the group by, I still return all companies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know which company rented the car last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case:

```
SELECT CompanyId
    from Company
WHERE
    -- Some Business Rules
ORDER BY CompanyId DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

But as i undestood You have to normalize Your DB first.
There should be 3 tables:
Company,
Car,
Car_to_company(
id Serial PK,
id_car integer FK,
id_company integer FK,
date_from date
etc...

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a group by in your main query for this.

Assuming that a date value is unique (i.e. there cannot be two rentals of the same car for the same date) you could do this with a clause like this:

```
...
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

See this: SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4) ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html